# Creating a jQuery "object" that is available between _layout and views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am coding in `ASP.NET MVC` *5.2*, and using `jQuery` as my primary script library. I am having a bit of a problem though, with the disparity between `_Layout` and views that use that layout.

Essentially, it goes like this

1. `_Layout` has **some** script that needs to run (initial wiring, progress bar, splash screen, etc)
2. Inheriting View has some script that needs to run (unique to that view)
3. `_Layout` has additional scripts that need to run **after** the view's unique scripts.

I have been trying a lot of ways to solve this, but it is actually proving to be a big problem. I have been frequently told that I should not create objects on the global namespace, so I am wondering if there are any other options to creating a script object that I can access in both views that isn't as damaging as global objects.

I have tried promises, and that is getting frustrating. I have tried events, and that doesn't really help because I cannot figure out what to attach the events to. I am told *not* to attach them to `$(document)`, but that is really one of the only things that will be shared between the view and the layout.

I understand that global objects are not considered good in javascript, but at this point I'm not sure what other options I have to make sure things execute in the right order.

## Update

The issue is more about "tooling" than it is about run time. It is true that when the actual view loads and runs, it is all pressed into one big happy page, and would work just fine. The issue is mostly that I have to split up the logic in the tooling (Visual Studio) to keep it from throwing errors and getting confused.

So I suppose it is more accurate to say it is a pseudo-problem.

I have attempted to split up the logic like this, but I think this is just another way of declaring a global object. I got the idea from the `Q.js` library.

#### Tasks.js

```
(function(definition) {
    // assign the task system
    tasks = definition();
})(function() {
    var list = [];

    function tasks() {

    };

    tasks.start = start;
    tasks.enqueue = enqueue;
    /*
     * start the task queue.
     */
    function start() {
        // make sure to raise a started event for things that need
        // to monitor it.
        $(this).trigger("started");
    };
    function enqueue(f) {
       // add the potential function to the queue to be processed later.
       list.push(f);
       $(this).trigger("enqueue", { item: f });
    };

    return tasks;

});
```

#### example usage

```
$(function(){
  $(tasks).on("started", function(){
    console.log("event called");
  });
  
  console.log("tasks", tasks);
  tasks.start();
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that the scripts in item #3 depend on some data that's generated in step #2?

Comment: It isn't so much that they depend on data, they just __have__ to come after step #2. They absolutely cannot execute before it is done.

Comment: That should be simple. Since your layout "wraps" your view, you should be able to put the scripts for #1 at the top of _layout, #2 in the view, and #3 at the bottom of _layout. But you are talking about trying to avoid global objects--what data are you struggling to not make global?

Comment: I'll update the question momentarily, sorry. Hang on a moment, please.

Comment: Alright, I've updated it a bit to be more clear. Sorry for the miscommunication.

Comment: You can have layouts inherit from layouts. I would create a layout that has everything all your pages use and then intermediate layouts that are used as needed (they contain stuff that you only need in certain circumstances). Combine this with various bundle objects that you render and all should be fairly manageable. You might also explore using @RenderSection for the one off scenarios.

Comment: I am a little confused by what you mean. The layout loads the progress bar, a splash screen, and makes sure certain data is pulled in the right order. The individual view loads a specific view model and MVVM binding. And then the Layout finishes up, closing the splash screen, progress bar, etc and wiring new events to `$(document).ajaxStart` and `$(document).ajaxStop`.

Comment: And please do not misunderstand me, I am not disagreeing with you. I just don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could go about this:

1. Use RequireJs to define Tasks as a module, then:

   ```
   require(['tasks'], function(tasks){
     $(tasks).on("started", function(){
       console.log("event called");
     });

     console.log("tasks", tasks);
     tasks.start();
   });
   ```
2. Use a global object, but namespace it:

   ```
   Ciel = Ciel || {};
   Ciel.tasks = Ciel.tasks || function(){
       var list = [];
       ...
   };
   ```
3. Tie your data to a specific dom element:

   ```
   <div class="ciel-tasks"></div>

   ...

   $(function() { $('.ciel-tasks').each(function() {
       var tasks = $(this);
       ...
   });
   ```

Comment: You say "use a global object, but namespace it. Why does this make a global object 'ok'? I don't mean that sarcastically, I genuinely don't understand

Comment: On #3. You can do that? You can just arbitrarily create a dummy HTML element to use for event propagation? That's valid? I assumed that would be massively frowned on.

Comment: I hadn't even considered using requirejs for it. I'm using requirejs already in my program for other things. I will absolutely explore that a bit more.

Comment: Okay... if I read this right, I could just make my task manager as a normal jQuery plugin, and ... simply attach it to a dummy DOM element, and work through it with the `.data()` function to do everything I need, without ever creating a global object? Like, that is safe? I hadn't even thought of that.

Comment: @Ciel: For #1: The primary reason that global objects are "bad" is that they may interfere with other people's global objects. Namespacing helps mitigate that problem. For #3: it largely depends on what "Tasks" represents--if there's some element on your page that you can consider the data to be tied to, then this approach makes sense. Would it make sense for you to want to display the tasks in a kind of dev console on your page? Is there value in being able to generate two task managers by creating two elements, or prevent any task management by removing the one that's there?

Comment: Each of these approaches has its advantages and disadvantages, and it's up to you to think about the relationship that this specific piece of javascript should have with other javascript, and with the DOM. It's usually wise to find a way to modularize your code in a way that mirrors how you think about your program's structure.

Comment: I am trying the namespacing method you showed,but am having a great deal of trouble with it. For some reason the functions are not executed within the `then` functions; http://jsbin.com/ruyih/1/edit

Comment: @Ciel: I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with Q to help you debug this.

Comment: You helped a lot. Thank you very much for your time. I think I'm finally getting somewhere

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're describing.  From JavaScript's perspective there's no such thing as "_Layout" and "Inheriting View."  There's only the resulting DOM delivered to the browser.  Any JavaScript code within that DOM can operate on anything else in that DOM.  So I'm not sure what any of this has to do with global namespace, events, `$(document)`, etc.  Perhaps you're overcomplicating the issue by assuming disparity between your views when, client side, no such disparity exists?

> _Layout has additional scripts that need to run after the view's unique scripts.

This sounds like it's just a matter of providing callbacks for operations so that they internally execute in the correct order.  For example, if the desired order is:

- Layout executes `initializeLayout()`
- View executes `initializeView()`
- Layout executes `completeLayout()`

Then you can pass these to one another as callbacks and the functions can internally execute those callbacks.  So in your Layout you might have something like this at the very top (such as in the header, as long as it's before the view is rendered):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initializeView(){} // placeholder for view-specific initialization
</script>
```

Then at the bottom with the rest of your scripts:

```
initializeLayout();
initializeView(completeLayout);
```

What this does is provide your views with an opportunity to *overwrite* that `initializeView` function.  If the view defines its own function called `initializeView` then *that* one will be executed instead of the placeholder one defined in the layout (remembering that the layout and the view are all one page to JavaScript).

(This also assumes you've elsewhere defined a `completeLayout` function, since that's what you want to execute after the view is initialized.)

Then in your view you can define that overwriting function:

```
function initializeView(callback) {
    // do some stuff...

    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
        callback();
    }
}
```

That will execute your view initialization code and then when it's complete will invoke the callback which was provided by the layout, so the layout will then execute its post-view-initialization code.  (Naturally, if any of this "initialization" code is asynchronous, you'll want to invoke callbacks in response to *those* asynchronous callbacks, etc.)

Comment: It is more an issue with tooling than it is with actual run time. If I declare things like this, it gets very confusing very quickly, and Visual Studio is constantly trying to tell me there are errors everywhere. It makes it a lot more difficult to know what is really a problem and what isn't. When the actual view renders, yes, it is all one big happy "page", but that isn't how it works in the tooling.

Comment: @Ciel: I can sympathize with that, and you're certainly welcome to continue to expend effort to address that.  However, in my experience the Visual Studio tooling for JavaScript is simply imperfect.  It's certainly improved *significantly* in recent versions, and will continue to do so.  But when you start dividing code among different files then Visual Studio faces the fundamental problem that those files in the server-side framework are entirely de-coupled *by design* but you as the developer know they will be re-coupled at runtime.  Issues like this are par for the course, really.

Comment: @Ciel: In short... I recommend not putting too much stock into Visual Studio's design-time JavaScript tooling.  Use what you can, but don't let it stop you from making otherwise clean and simple JavaScript code.

Comment: I think you are correct that the tooling is imperfect, but in all truth this just shouldn't be hard. I need to figure this out to understand what I am doing. The fact that I don't entirely understand why global objects are so bad just shows how little I truly know. I almost consider this a side-challenge that I want to solve for the sake of grasping it.

Comment: I also really don't like the whole "put scripts at the bottom of the page" approach. Everything I've ever learned about Javascript has taught me to run things within the DOM onReady stage. This is kind of disparate across tutorials, as I've seen it done both ways practically everywhere. I'm unsure if this is really a difference in performance or just personal preference, but it makes a lot more sense to me

Comment: @Ciel: There may be additional technical reasons to put the scripts at the bottom of the page, and indeed in most simple cases it may not even make a difference.  For me the difference is that the page content loads in its entirety, presenting the user with the UI, before the client-side code is even processed.  That way errors in code (or even disabled JavaScript entirely) won't interfere with the loading of that interface (and it will be ever so slightly faster to load the interface).  As for the DOM onReady state... that has nothing to do with where code is physically located.

Comment: See, that is a bit confusing to me. When I tried that, I got bitten very hard by asynchronous javascript. So I suppose I did it wrong. I am reading over your answer more carefully now, and will give it a try after lunch. Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: Another reason I am a bit hesitant is because I want to keep as much of my code in external files as possible, so I can minify them. There is actually some proprietary stuff in there and I would prefer not to expose it outright. Though if I just put functions in an external file that don't 'belong' to anything, isn't that just the same as putting them as global functions/objects?

Comment: And to be clear, I'm absolutely not disagreeing with you. I'm just inexperienced, and trying to find what works best for me.

Comment: @Ciel: Keeping the JavaScript code in external files doesn't change the namespacing or globalization of them.  Those files are essentially "injected" into the DOM wherever they're referenced, the JavaScript code itself doesn't change. Though with `.js` files you may be able to "assist" the Visual Studio tooling by adding reference comments to the tops of the files, such as: `/// <reference path="someOtherFile.js" />`  This tells Visual Studio at design time to include `someOtherFile.js` in its intellisense and whatnot, but does nothing runtime.

Comment: That does make sense. Though I was under the impression that the page ran top to bottom, in the order that it was seen, but everything was asynchronous. I've avoided putting scripts at the bottom because I was taught that it is hit or miss. For instance, if you have a lot of HTML, it might not all finish rendering by the time it gets to the javascript, and that can cause issues. This is why I was taught to wrap all of my JS in the `$(document).ready` function. So that is not true?

Comment: @Ciel: Code is evaluated from top to bottom, yes.  By wrapping code in `$(document).ready()` it's still being evaluated, but the function being passed to `ready()` isn't evaluated until the document's ready event is triggered.  So it doesn't really matter where that code exists, since it's going to be invoked at a specific point in the life of the document anyway.

Comment: That does make sense, thank you. I will reconsider my approach. Though I am still going to be looking at the other answers too. I'm not nearly good enough with javascript to try and argue any of that, I'm merely doing it the way I've learned. And if that is incorrect, I have a lot more to catch up on than I thought. So will scripts run in parallel to the HTML rendering, if they are not metered behind an event wrapper?

Comment: For example, let's say that, in one page there is 2.5 MB worth of HTML (I'm not saying this is how my page is, just a hyperbole) and the scripts are at the bottom of the page. Will the fact that the browser is taking longer to render that HTML mean the scripts won't run until it is all rendered, or will it "start" rendering the HTML, and move on, and "start" on the scripts at the same time?

Comment: @Ciel: They will, yes.  For example, if you identify an element: `$('#someElement')` *before* that element on the page then the script will be evaluated and no matching element found.  That's the most common reason for putting things in the document's ready event.

Comment: Right, yes. That is __exactly__ why I do everything in the onready event.

Comment: In the case of that large page, all of the markup is going to be processed and rendered before the script at the bottom is evaluated.  That isn't to say that everything will be done, external resources aren't done loading (such as images or style sheets, loaded asynchronously as separate requests), but the DOM is processed.  (Which begs an interesting question about separately loaded JavaScript files, for which I do not have an answer.)

Comment: Alright. So what I am understanding at this point is that you're not telling me not to use the `onready`, but rather you just have a different style of coding than I do, and I misunderstood it.

Comment: Sorry for all the responses, I'm mostly talking to myself a lot. It's just kind of how I think.

Comment: @Ciel: I'm absolutely not decrying the use of `onready`, that is correct.  It most definitely *should* be used :)